# Not able to open the image after selecting it using 'accept' tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have made a form which has an input box and a browse button alongside.

When I click the browse button, I want to select an image such that the image name or the image address that i have selected must appear in the input box.

I have made use of the `accept` tag in HTML. Here is the code that i have used:

```
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    Browse <input type="file" accept="image/*">
</span>
```

When I browse for the image, and select a particular image and click open, nothing happens really.

Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It has to work fine, no issue is there. Can you provide full code?

Comment: how do i do that? i am new to this...

Comment: put some same code here or in fiddler and update your question.

Comment: or else refer this https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp link and try to find out the issue.

Comment: Enhanced formatting and better use of syntactic sugar.